# Scope function not responsive in directive link using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my html

```
<example-directive id="my_id" ng-blur="test()"></example-directive>
```

Here is my directive

```
app.directive('exampleDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
       label: "@",
    },
    template: '<span class="some_input"> <input required/></span>',
    controller: function($scope, $element){
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attr) {
     // this is not responsive when blur out
      scope.test = function(){
        console.log("what is up");
      }
     // this is responsive when blur out
     el.on('blur', function(){
      console.log("this is up");
       });
    }
  }
})
```

When I

```
$("#my_id").blur()
```

in console, only

```
"this is up"
```

showed up

I am not sure why I can't access the scope function when a blur event occured in `example-directive`

Answer (score 1):

As you are using blur event on custom element, it won't work. You need to pass that element inside isolated scope, so that directive can have access to that method by adding `blur: '&ngBlur'` inside the isolated scope. Where `blur` variable give access to specified `ngBlur` attribute function.

```
scope: {
   label: "@",
   blur: '&ngBlur'
},
```

Then you could use that event inside your directive `blur` event

```
 el.on('blur', function(){
    console.log("this is up");
    //here we need to run digest cycle manually,
    //as we are dealing from outside angular context.
    $timeout(function(){ //include `$timeout` dependency in directive
        scope.blur();
    });
 });
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get it, `el.on("blur", function(){console.log("already");}` worked when I invoke a blur event. I was just curious why a function in scope couldn't catch the blur event, are we saying that if I want to have a scope that listen to a blur event it will have to be in `el.on` ?

Comment: @Jal the way you have it the function isn't in directive isolated scope it is in the parent scope

Comment: Ah, so are we saying that `scope.test` is in the parent scope so its unavailable to the directive?